# Unity - relate wall clock time to physics time (in fixed update)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ros2

I am involved in a project that is building software for a robot that uses ROS2 to support the robot's autonomy code. To streamline development, we are using a model of our robot built in Unity to simulate the physics. In Unity, we have analogues for the robot's sensors and actuators - the Unity sensors use Unity's physics state to generate readings that are published to ROS2 topics and the actuators subscribe to ROS2 topics and process messages that invoke the actuators and implement the physics outcomes of those actuators within Unity. Ultimately, we will deploy the (unmodified) autonomy software on a physical robot that has real sensors and actuators and uses the real world for the physics.

In ROS2, we are scripting with python and in Unity the scripting uses C#.

It is our understanding that, by design, the wall clock time that a Unity fixed update call executes has no direct correlation with the "physics" time associated with the fixed update. This makes sense to us - simulated physics can run out of synchronization with the real world and still give the right answer.

Some of our planning software (ROS2/python) wants to initiate an actuator at a particular time, expressed as floating point seconds since the (1970) epoch. For example, we might want to start decelerating at a particular time so that we end up stopped one meter from the target. Given the knowledge of the robot's speed and distance from the target (received from sensors), along with an understanding of the acceleration produced by the actuator, it is easy to plan the end of the maneuver and have the actuation instructions delivered to the actuator well in advance of when it needs to initiate. Note: we specifically don't want to hold back sending the actuation instructions until it is time to initiate, because of uncertainties in message latency, etc. - if we do that, we will never end up exactly where we intended.

And in a similar fashion, we expect sensor readings that are published (in a fixed update in Unity/C#) to likewise be timestamped in floating point seconds since the epoch (e.g., the range to the target object was 10m at a particular recent time). We don't want to timestamp the sensor reading with the time it was received because of unknown latency from the time the sensor value was current and the time it was received in our ROS2 node.

When our (Unity) simulated sensors publish a reading (based on the physics state during a fixed update call), we don't know what real-world/wall clock timestamp to associated with it - we don't know which 20ms of real time that particular fixed update correlates to.

Likewise, when our our Unity script that is associated with an actuator is holding a message that says to initiate actuation at a particular real-world time, we don't know if that should happen in the current fixed update because we don't know the real-world time that the fixed update correlates to.

The Unity Time methods all seem to deal with time relative to the start of the game (basically, a dynamically determined epoch).

We have tried capturing the wall clock time and time since game start in a MonoBehavior's Start, but this seems to put us off by a handful of seconds when the fixed updates are running (with the exact time shift being variable between runs).

How to crosswalk between the Unity game-start-based epoch and a fixed-start epoch (e.g., 1970)?

An example: This code will publish the range to the target, along with the time of the measurement. This gets executed every 20ms by Unity.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
        RangeMsg targetRange = new RangeMsg();
        targetRange.time_s = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() / 1000.0;
        targetRange.range_m = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, chaser.transform.position);
        ros.Publish(topicName, targetRange);
}
```

On the receiving end, let's say that we are calculating the speed toward the target:

```
def handle_range(self, msg):
    if self.last_range is not None:
        diff_s = msg.time_s - self.last_range.time_s
        if diff_s != 0.0:
            diff_range_m = self.last_range.range_m - msg.range_m
            speed = Speed()
            speed.time_s = msg.time_s
            speed.speed_mps = diff_range_m / diff_s
            self.publisher.publish(speed)
    self.last_range = msg
```

If the messages are really published exactly every 20ms, then this all works. But if Unity gets behind and runs several fixed updates one after another to get caught up, then the speed gets computed as much higher than it should (because each cycle, 20ms of movement is applied, but the cycles may be executed within a millisecond of each other).

If instead we use Unity's time for timestamping the messages with

```
 targetRange.time_s = Time.fixedTimeAsDouble;
```

then the range and time stay in synch and the speed calculation works great, even in the face of some major hiccup in Unity processing. But, then the rest of our code that lives in the 1970 epoch has no idea what time `targetRange.time_s` really is.

Comment: Maybe its helps to understand the problem better if you try to explain the problem as summarized and simple possible in a short paragraph. Adding a numeric simple example can also help.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Does the edit make it more clear? Or less?

Comment: I think it helps. Maybe stupid but just a naive think I have. If things work on the unity side, why use a time as a target? Can't you calculate the amount of time you wish your code to run (with [datetime.now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-7.0) and [Time.realtimeSinceStartup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) etc...) instead of setting a target time?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay If that is the only answer, we probably can make it work. It just means that the 95% of our code that is running on the robot now needs to be aware of this weird time epoch. If we have to go that route, we will need to get clever about how we minimize the impact to the autonomy code. It would be WAY easier if we could find a way to directly and accurately translate between time schemes.

Comment: I would start the communication with a "time sync", where I send a few actual time from Unity, so I can determine the communication delay on the receiver side (or if the whole thing runs locally where the latency is negligible, this can be skipped). My point is, that if we have a reference time on both sides, we can detect if a message is delayed and we can correct the timings.